# How can I put a style to content before or after?

Tags: html, css

I want to make for a client a button with :after and :before selector.
And the text from :before content: "" is basic.

```
div:after {"E-mail"} and div:hover:after {"exemple@exemple.com"}
```

How cand I design content text like normal text?

[image]

Comment: What is it exactly you want to achieve? It's not quite clear.
Also: Can you please share a JSFiddle (containing your HTML and CSS) illustrating your problem?

Comment: @BenPhilipp, he is trying to insert HTML content using CSS `:after`

Comment: I want to Style the text from e-mail like rest of the text.

Comment: @odedta: It appears not. He already appears to know about the `content:` property, as he already achieved displaying his :before pseudo elements. (I don't know why he wrote the wrong code above).

@Razvan: See answer below for syntax. And you can apply styles to your pseudo elements like you can for any other selectors: just define the same specs, like `div:after{content: "E-mail"; font-size: 14pt; color: #666;}` etc.
But setting your styles for the div should result in the :before **inheriting** the style.
Without more code (HTML, more CSS) we can't pinpoint your problem source.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the pseudo-element will inherit the parent style.
However, you can specifically style the pseudo-element just like any other, if needed:

See my Example explaining the relationships:

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/L9v24xwx/

```css
div.styleme{
color:#f00;
font-size: 14pt;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

div span{
color:#00f;
font-size: 14pt;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

div:after{
content: "E-mail";
}

#defined:after{
color:#0f0;
font-size: 14pt;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="styleme">Pseudo Element inheriting Style</div>
<div><span>Style only applied to &lt;SPAN&gt; tag</span></div>
<div id="defined">Style explicitly (re-)defined for Pseudo Element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div:after { 
    content: "E-mail";
} 

div:hover:after {
    content: "exemple@exemple.com";
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

There you go, please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp for learning how to use `:after` selector.

Comment: I know how to use it. I want to design the text from content: "text" like other texts